# MapView - Trace and draw route on the way he travels?

Tags: android

I'm trying to draw a route in a mapView from the current location (got from GPS) to the way he travels.

I am able to fetch the location of the user as he moves in a particular direction, but I was not able to draw the path.

What is the best way to draw the route path as he moves from place to place continuously?

I want the method to be good (in terms of performance).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to keep track of the current location & previous location (in global variable for example) in order to draw the path [except the first time you only have current location, so you do nothing until the next point].

```
        int x1 = -1, y1 = -1, x2 = -1, y2 = -1;
        Paint paint = new Paint();
        paint.setColor(Color.rgb(0x7b, 0x7b, 0xff));
        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        paint.setStrokeWidth(5);

                Point prevloc = new Point();
                mv.getProjection().toPixels(new GeoPoint((int (prevlocation.getLatitude()*1.0E6),(int) (prevlocation.getLongitude()*1.0E6)), prevloc);
                Point loc = new Point();
                mv.getProjection().toPixels(new GeoPoint((int (location.getLatitude()*1.0E6),(int) (location.getLongitude()*1.0E6)), loc);
                x2 = prevloc.x;
                y2 = prevloc.y;
                if (first)
                {
                    x2 = loc.x;
                    y2 = loc.y;
                }
                if (!first) {
                    canvas.drawLine(x1, y1, x2, y2, paint);
                }
                x1 = x2;
                y1 = y2;
```

This will be called in `draw()` and you to somehow call this draw function through drawing overlay in `onLocationChanged()` function.

note: canvas and mv are parameters passed to `draw()` function and first is a global boolean variable to indicate this is the first point you get or not.

Comment: according to you this is best way or may try for any other approach

Comment: I can't assure you this is the best approach, but this is good for a start to make you want to do happen, then think of efficiency, of course if you have better solution you can answer your own question and mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
public void draw(Canvas canvas, MapView mapv, boolean shadow){
    super.draw(canvas, mapv, shadow);
    Projection projection = mapv.getProjection();
    Path p = new Path();
    for (int i = 0; i < geoPointsArray.size(); i++) {
        if (i == geoPointsArray.size() - 1) {
            break;
        }
        Point from = new Point();
        Point to = new Point();
        projection.toPixels(geoPointsArray.get(i), from);
        projection.toPixels(geoPointsArray.get(i + 1), to);
        p.moveTo(from.x, from.y);
        p.lineTo(to.x, to.y);
    }
    Paint mPaint = new Paint();
    mPaint.setStyle(Style.STROKE);
    mPaint.setColor(Color.GREEN);
    mPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
    mPaint.setStrokeWidth(5);
    canvas.drawPath(p, mPaint);
    mapv.invalidate();
    super.draw(canvas, mapv, shadow);
}//draw()
```

We can use the above method to draw the route as we move from place to place. `geoPointsArray` is an array of the received locations.

Comment: Nice Answer. This idea would be the best, but just keep in mind that we don't want geoPointsArray to be massive & to be able to track them, we would need constantly add points to geoPointsArray.